# What methods exist to introduce dead-time in a MOSFET H-bridge?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, driver, h-bridge

What methods exist to introduce dead-time in a MOSFET H-bridge?

(to prevent shoot-through)

(other than software methods, or using MOSFET driver ICs with internal dead-time generators)

Comment: You mean "break before make" behavior? Draw the circuit you are using / want to modify.

Comment: you can integrate multiple coil drains in a single sensing application and globally apply a turn-off multiplier. or compute the motor switching time and add a latched offset to each cycles

Comment: Many drivers have separate inputs for controlling the high and low MOSFET. You can add additional dead time circuitry there which is a better place then on the low impedance outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people use only resistors and diodes, in the gate drive connection, to ensure no software problems can destroy the needed timing, like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWyYjO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. going through the web i also found this one: http://www.modularcircuits.com/blog/articles/h-bridge-secrets/h-bridge-control/